# discussing meaning in language - poetry and song lyrics

Tags: discussion

Not really a language question (probably more of a meta question really), but where is the best forum to discuss meaning / interpretation of poetry / song lyrics - pragmatics, inference, metaphor, contextual relevance, cultural context, interpretation, intention, etc.? Have looked at area 51 poetry but has 2 followers :/

Comment: I can empathize; I like *interpretation*. Have you tried writers?

Comment: I don't know of any online forums, though the first place I'd look would be the Poetry Foundation. However, I can point you to some online resources, so you can get a feel of some other ideas. [Haj Ross](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/) has been analyzing poetry linguistically for decades; look for "poetics" papers in the link. And don't forget the **sound** of the poem -- poetry is an oral medium, first, last, and foremost; writing has some cute steps to perform in the dance, but it's the sounds that ultimately command the memory.